# Lateral join in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, lateral-join

I have the following lateral join that I am trying to migrate to Snowflake from Postgres

```
select * 
from service f 
join lateral
     (select s.*
      from inferred s
      where s.patient = f.patient
      order by s.from_date desc
      limit 1
     ) s
    on 1=1
    limit 23
```

I am getting the following error in Snowflake -

```
SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300010:1094633624; incident 5081153.
```

There are patients in the service table and the `inferred` table. The query tries to join patients from the service table with the latest record of the same patient from the `inferred` table.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and desired results?

Comment: I would suggest opening a support case for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact Snowflake support.  That's an internal error.  When you contact support give them your account details and the QUERY_ID you were executing.